# DataAdapter update method - which connection does it use?

Tags: c#, connection, dataadapter

Sorry for the probably stupid question. Since I found nothing about it on the internets, its probably totally obvious and I'm just to blind to see?!

I'm trying to update a table in a database from a dataset via DataAdapter.Update(dataset)

But there is no possiblity to set the connection, the DA should use.

Where does the DA know how to connect to the DB? Or do I misunderstand the concept of the dataadapter?

my current code is like:

```
protected DataSet UpdateDataSet(DataSet ds)
{
   DataSet dsChanges = new DataSet();
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

   dsChanges = ds.GetChanges();

   //Update DataSet
   da.Update(dsChanges);

   ds.Merge(dsChanges);
   return ds;
}
```

I just wrote this and became suspicious how (or if) it works... I havent tested it so far, since I gotta write some other code before I can test it properly

Thank you ppl, StackOVerflow FTW!

Comment: You are instantiating a blank dataset (dsChanges) then are overwriting it with another.  Don't initialise itlike this.

Comment: thanks for this hint! This would be better(?): 
            
DataSet dsChanges = ds.GetChanges();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A SqlDataAdapter needs to take in a SqlCommand object, which has a SqlConnection object tied to it.  That's pretty much how the hierarchy breaks down.

As for ***how*** you go about doing that, there are options for passing them into the constructor, as well as setting the various properties after construction.

Here's an [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand.aspx) with examples of selecting, inserting, updating, and deleting.

*FTA:*

```
public static SqlDataAdapter CreateCustomerAdapter(
    SqlConnection connection)
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

    // Create the SelectCommand.
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers " +
        "WHERE Country = @Country AND City = @City", connection);

    // Add the parameters for the SelectCommand.
    command.Parameters.Add("@Country", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15);
    command.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15);

    adapter.SelectCommand = command;

    // Create the InsertCommand.
    command = new SqlCommand(
        "INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, CompanyName) " +
        "VALUES (@CustomerID, @CompanyName)", connection);

    // Add the parameters for the InsertCommand.
    command.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID");
    command.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 
        40, "CompanyName");

    adapter.InsertCommand = command;

    // Create the UpdateCommand.
    command = new SqlCommand(
        "UPDATE Customers SET CustomerID = @CustomerID, " + 
        "CompanyName = @CompanyName " +
        "WHERE CustomerID = @oldCustomerID", connection);

    // Add the parameters for the UpdateCommand.
    command.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID");
    command.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 
        40, "CompanyName");
    SqlParameter parameter = command.Parameters.Add(
        "@oldCustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID");
    parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;

    adapter.UpdateCommand = command;

    // Create the DeleteCommand.
    command = new SqlCommand(
        "DELETE FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID", connection);

    // Add the parameters for the DeleteCommand.
    parameter = command.Parameters.Add(
        "@CustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID");
    parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;

    adapter.DeleteCommand = command;

    return adapter;
}
```

Comment: ok, thats what I do when I try to retrieve data. I pass a command object. But the update method of DataAdapter does only accept a DataSet (and other stuff, but no command object)

Comment: @MAD9 The SqlDataAdapter also has an UpdateCommand property that you can assign with a SqlCommand object to suite your needs.  This also works for insertion and deletion as well.

Comment: Ok, thanks again ppl. The problem was, that I didn't know where I should get that command object from since I not explicitly had a SQL string or so.